# Is it Possible checkbox won't check if there a value in row from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, mysqli

Is it Possible checkbox won't check if there a value in row from database?

This is my Example Table

```
item_name | PR     | checkbox  |

ballpen   | pr100  |     □     |
pencil    | pr111  |     □     |
Paper     | pr500  |     □     |
Clip      |        |     □     |

< Edit > < Add >
```

Example the item_name `Clip` has no `PR` and when I Check the `Clip` row and click `Edit` it won't allow to check it or retain to uncheck. I want to validate base on `Edit` button if there's a value from database.

This is my short code

app_list2.php

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");

    //unset the session value 
    $_SESSION['content'] = '';

    $drop     = $_POST['drop_1'];
    $tier_two = $_POST['tier_two'];

    $where = "WHERE a.app_cn='$drop' AND a.app_plan_no='$tier_two'";

    $result1 = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT a.*, a.counter as sucks, b.counter, b.pr
    FROM app a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase_request b
    ON a.counter=b.counter
    $where 
    GROUP BY a.counter ORDER BY a.item_name
");
?>
  <?php
    echo '<table id="tfhover" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">PR</th>
        <th rowspan="2" id="none"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['app_cn'] != '') {
            echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['pr'] . '</td>
            <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['sucks'] . '"></td>
       </tr>';
        }
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
    $sPageContent        = ob_get_clean();
    $_SESSION['content'] = $sPageContent;
    echo $_SESSION['content'];
} else {
    if (isset($_SESSION['content'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['content'];
    }
}
?>
  <a class="button" href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" onclick="f1.action='editpr.php'; return true;"><span><b>Edit Purchase Request</b></span></a>

  <a class="button" href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" onclick="f1.action='addpr.php'; return true;"><span><b>Add to Purchase Request</b></span></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it doesn't need to be done via JavaScript or jQuery.

Set the `disabled` parameter on your input checkbox: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rx8AC/)

```
<input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="XYZ" disabled />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

I don't know php so can't help you on that front, but pseudo code:

```
// in your while loop - replace the existing line of code
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['sucks'] . '" ' . elementDisabled($row['pr']) .'/></td>

// function to test whether PR is empty
// put this on the line after the second <?php
function elementDisabled($input)
{
     if  (!isset($input) || trim($input)==='')
     {
         return "disabled";
     }
}
```

Comment: How about the item that has a PR? I can't edit if all of the checkbox was disabled

Comment: Sure, in your `while loop` you need to check the PR for each loop. If there is no PR then add disabled to the input. I'll add some pseudo code since I don't know php

Comment: I'm having error with elementDisabled($row['pr']) and where I include the function code?

Comment: not surprised, it's pseudo code, i.e. not real code. I'm not a php developer so I don't know the exact syntax. I've edited best I could after googling, try that. Also looks at: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_functions.htm Hopefully someone else will be along to help if that doesn't work

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm still hoping for someone who could help me about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple code change on you check box, added one condition & disable attribute on your checkbox & sending you complete while loop:

```
while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['app_cn'] != '') {
        echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['pr'] . '</td>
        <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['sucks'] . '"'.($row['item_name'] == ""?"disabled ":"").'></td>
   </tr>';
    }
}
```

Code is not tested but will definitely work.